# Load xml report directly from Azure SQL Reporting Server

Tags: xml, azure, reporting-services

Is it possible to fetch directly the xml report from Azure SQL Reporting Server?

I would like to open directly same report that you can save from report viewer web page "XML file with report data".

Comment: [SQL Reporting will discontinue service on October 31, 2014.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-reporting/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you question is to access the XML data directly from Report Server you sure can do it. If you will access the Reporting Server URL in browser the XML data will render in the browser or if you are accessing it pro-grammatically then it depends on how to access the received data.

SQL Azure reporting support mostly all the system data types found in SQL Server along with  specialized data types such as the spatial data types geography and geometry, hierarchyId, and XML. XML data type is supported, however typed XML & XML indexing not supported yet.

After you created the Report Server URL ([as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh403968.aspx)), you can [access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh403971.aspx) the same reporting URL by passing XML format type as below:

https://_Reporting_Server_ID_.reporting.windows.net/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?% ReportName&rs:Format=XML&rs:Command=Render

You can create all the reports already in the reporting server so you can access in different format either from URL or from Report Viewer control.

Comment: It works! But now I still have to get pass Username & Password dialog. I'll post new question about that one.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the ReportServer URL via the browser isn't really an approach I would recommend since it was only put there to help with basic troubleshooting. It isn't fully compatible with all browsers, so you may see some inconsistencies.

Another approach would be to access the web service programmatically or via an programmatically instantiated version of the ReportViewer control. With these two approaches, you can pull down the report in whatever format you want as a binary object and then do whatever you want with it. Although not specifically targeted at the scenario you are doing, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2012/11/12/using-a-windows-azure-worker-role-to-generate-reports-using-azure-reporting.aspx does lay out how to access the Azure RS instance (and really any SSRS instance for that matter) programmatically.